# chose category in plugin

Tags: categories

I am making a plugin to upload records and I want to put the option to choose category, also I would like those categories to be the ones that are normally created with wordpress, but I don't know if can

How do I put the option to choose category in the form?

Comment: There's no code in your question for the form or the form handler, can you edit your question to include it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDs are your friends. Get the category list using [get_category](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories) (i'm assuming we are talking about the in-built Wordpress "category" taxonomy, which slug is *category*).

```
$categories = get_categories( array(
    'hide_empty' => false // This is optional
) );
```

Use the obtained category list in the output of your <select> field:

```
 <?php // get $selected_term_id from somewhere ?> 
 <select name="category_id">
       <?php foreach( $categories as $category ) : ?>
           <?php $is_selected = $category->term_id == $selected_term_id ? 'selected' : ''; ?> 
           <option value="<?php esc_attr_e( $category->term_id ); ?>" <?php echo $is_selected; ?>><?php esc_html_e( $category->cat_name ); ?></option>
       <?php endforeach; ?>
 </select>
```

Comment: Ok. the function works, the categories are listed, but an association is not established between the id of the category and the id of the article. The problem is that the plugin works with its own table (wp_biblio) and I understand that the categories function is associated with the wp_posts table, so my question is how to associate the categories with the plugin table

Comment: In my plugin table there must be a specific field related to categories, because I have one called post_category, but I think it is no longer used?

Answer (score -1):

you can try this code:

```
$parent_cat = get_query_var('cat');
wp_list_categories("child_of=$parent_cat&show_count=1");
```

you will get a list of top-level categories at the output

if you need an example of selecting a category, you can do this:

```
$args = array(
    'taxonomy'      => 'tags',
    'parent'        => 0, // get top level categories
    'orderby'       => 'name',
    'order'         => 'ASC',
    'hierarchical'  => 1,
    'pad_counts'    => 0
);

$categories = get_categories( $args );

echo '<select name="category_id">';

foreach ( $categories as $category ){
    echo '<option value="'.$category->ID.'">'.$category->name.'</option>';               
}

echo '</select>';
```

after submitting the form, you need to process the POST request:

```
wp_set_post_categories( $your_record_id,  array( $_POST['category_id'] ), true);
```

Comment: Please explain how does offer a category selection for uploads.

Comment: fuxia, sorry, I have completed my example

Comment: the function wp_list_categories works, the categories are listed, but an association is not established between the id of the category and the id of the article. The problem is that the plugin works with its own table (wp_biblio) and I understand that the categories function is associated with the wp_posts table, so my question is how to associate the categories with the plugin table

Comment: after selecting a category you can set up a link using the function: wp_set_post_categories( $post_ID, $post_categories, true);

Comment: where  $post_ID - ID your record in DB,  $post_categories - array of IDs for the selected categories, true - add to existing categories (false - remove from existing categories and add to specified categories)